# Does mingw support clr safe?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, clr, type-safety

I'm wanting to [compile C++ extensions to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc912f03.aspx), from the docs

> Safe mode: Run verifiably typesafe code; compiled with `/clr:safe.`

Does `mingw`'s C++ compile support `/clr:safe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Common Language Runtime (CLR) of the Microsoft .NET framework has no
application to non-Microsoft, non-.NET compilers. The several Windows ports
of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) that can be meant by "mingw" are all non-.NET, native compilers. Microsoft's
managed C++-like language, C++/CLI, to which `/clr:safe` applies, isn't C++.

`/clr:safe` directs the Microsoft compiler to generate an output file that contains
no native code, only verifiably typesafe Microsoft Intermediate Language code for
managed execution with the CLR. By definition a native compiler cannot provide
an equivalent option: generating native code is what they do.

If what you are after is *how to compile C++ with the strictest diagnostics GCC can
provide*, a diligent answer would be off-puttingly long, since there is a plethora
of options for diagnosing corner cases of safety. Settle at least on:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

(see [3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options))
and perhaps augment the list as prompted by bitter exerience and mounting paranoia ;)

Beyond the regular static diagnostics another level of hygeine is available
through the large `-fsanitize=...` family of the [3.11 Program Instrumentation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html).

Comment: "Microsoft's managed C++-like language, C++/CLI, to which /clr:safe applies, isn't C++." that makes so much sense, I was looking for information on that. I have 0-idea of the MS Landscape so I'm sure this was a novice error, but that hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Specifically what I wanted to do was use C++ in SQL Server in Linux (or C) and not the CLI.